# How does collision in array of objects occur?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, collision-detection

The problem is my collision detection. Which don't work as expected.

I tried to make a shooter game. Its code was

```
        function rect(rect1, rect2) {
                return (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
                    rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
                    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h &&
                    rect1.h + rect1.y > rect2.y)
        }
        function a() {
            requestAnimationFrame(a);
            player.draw();
            if (tr<il) {
                tr += 1;
            }
            else if (tr>=il) {
                ag.pms.push(new pm(c.width,Math.random()*(c.height/2)));
                tr=0;
            }
            for (let i=0;i<ag.pms.length;i++) {
                const m=ag.pms[i];
                m.r();
            }
            for (let i=0;i<ag.z.length;i++) {
                const t=ag.z[i];
                t.r();
            }
            ag.z.forEach(lazer=>{
                for (let i = 0; i < ag.pms.length; i++) {
                    const rect2 = ag.pms[i];
                    if (rect(lazer, rect2)) {
                        lazer.d = true;
                        rect2.d = true;
                    }
                }
            });
                
        }
        a();
```

. I thought it will work and it worked well but its collision detection is not working.
I viewed many tutorials but none of them was able to teach me how it works after spending almost 2 hours I had written the code above and it worked half way but when increasing score I thought killing enemies will increase score. So I made collision-detection code above to detect collision between enemy class pm and lazer class l. But it won't work. Can anyone help me finding the problem in my code I am not getting any errors but collision-detection won't work too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)